# vector data not adding in while loop

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

I am trying to add the elements of a vector of doubles (belonging to a class called path) into a double called dist using a for loop twice. I want it to add all the distances inside the class vector for the first iteration and then at the end set the double dist back to zero and add them up again. However, when I run it, it works fine the first time as it prints out the correct answer of 3, but the double ends up being 0 by the time it prints out the second time and after the loop is done. It looks like it is not adding the vector's data. Why is this happening? Thanks for any help

```
class Path
{
  public:
      vector<double> distance;
      vector<double> safety;
};

int main()
{
     int i = 0;
     int k = 0;
     vector<Path*> paths; 

     Path* paths.at(0) = new Path;
     Path* paths.at(1) = new Path;
     paths.at(0)->distance.push_back(1.0);
     paths.at(0)->distance.push_back(2.0);
     paths.at(1)->distance.push_back(1.0);
     paths.at(1)->distance.push_back(2.0)
     double dist = 0;

     for(k = 0; k < paths.size(); k++)
     {

         for(i = 0; i< paths.at(k)->distance.size(); i++)
         {
              dist += paths.at(i)->distance.at(i);
         }
         cout << dist << endl;
         dist = 0;
    }
    delete paths.at(0); delete paths.at(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But outside the first loop you do dist = 0;, so you clear the value

Comment: Except some compiler errors , everything works as intended. The code prints 3 the first time , 3 the second time and when exiting main function `dist` is 0 because after printing it you set it to 0

Comment: And, where is the `delete` ??

Comment: Sorry this isn't my main code. My actual code is much longer so I was trimming it down and forgot the delete. 
But as mentioned in the description, the 0 is printed out the second time, not 3 as expected.

Comment: Please consider editing the code, so no compiler errors are there.

Comment: You have find the code that actually causes the problem and update the question. Otherwise you can use a debugger. If you use Visual Studio go to a line you are interested in inspecting and press F9, Press then F5 and the code can be executed onwards step by step with F10/F11

Comment: @ddwong - I ran the same code on Ideone.com and it gave me expected output. Two times 3 is printed.

Comment: I am using the VS debugger. I don't see why people here assume others don't use debugging and try to find the problem themselves before coming to ask. 
I am running on VS 2010 and dist stays 0 for the entire second iteration of the outer loop even though it's passing through the inner loop.

Comment: @ddwong they assume because they don't know if you used it or not. Also finding such a problem is most of the times trivial so it's safe to assume that you did not used a debugger. If you use it, check all the places where dist is added and see if they get called or not. You might clear the vector after a print or something and the for loop never gets executed again. Also you can use memory breakpoint to check if something else sets the value to 0

Comment: @ddwong if dist remains 0 probably the elements from the vector are 0

Comment: Edited the code to look more like my actual code (which is very lengthy). Sorry for screwing up the question. Anyways, I am using the debugger and I am checking the vector and the distance elements inside the vector are not zero.

Comment: I'll probably end up asking another question and post my actual code since it was a dumb idea to post something that might look like my code but does not act like it. So if someone believes it's best to do this and wants to shut this down, go ahead.

Comment: @ddwong how big is your code?

Comment: Well the problem is in one class function which i tried simulating above. But there are 3 source files (one 250 lines the others about 30) 5 header files, and one small main. 
So it is difficult to just post the portion that is failing without having the need to give a complete background of the program.

Comment: NEVERMIND!! I found the problem. In my code, on the inner loop, I was using '.at(k)' rather than '.at(i)'

Thanks for the help everyone and sorry for the waste of memory

Answer (score 0):

```
for(k = 0; k < route -> distance.size(); k++)
{
    for(i = 0; i< route->distance.size(); i++)
    {
        dist += route->distance.at(i);
    }

    cout << dist << endl;
    dist = 0;
}
```

This will give you `k` outputs (that is, it will iterator over the vector `k` times).  If you just want to iterate over the vector twice, then this is not how you want to write your loops.  Instead, you'll want 2 separate (not nested) loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < route->distance.size(); ++i)
{
    dist += route->distance[i];
}
cout << dist << endl;

dist = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < route->distance.size(); ++k)
{
    dist += route->distance[k];
}
cout << dist << endl;
```

Or you could use a function that would do that for you:

```
dist = std::accumulate(route->distance.begin(), route->distance.end(), 0);
```

**Edit**

With your update, you now have invalid operations:

```
vector<Path*> paths; 
Path* paths.at(0) = new Path; // at(0) does not exist!  exception will be thrown
Path* paths.at(1) = new Path; // same here
```

Comment: No. The thing is, that this is just an example of what I am doing with this code. I have to use these nested loops because in my actual code I have to iterate through more than one path. I'll edit my code to make it more clear and a better example of what I'm doing because I gave a bad outline.

Comment: @ddwong What is it you are actually trying to do?  The memory problems you have in your sample code make it impossible to narrow down your actual problem.  If this is any resemblance to what you have, your problem is how you are dealing with memory.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a bug:

```
dist += paths.at(i)->distance.at(i);
```

Should be:

```
dist += paths.at(k)->distance.at(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's C++, use its power:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Path
{
    std::vector<double> distance;
    std::vector<double> safety;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Path> paths{
        {
            { 1.0, 2.0 }, {}
        },
        {
            { 3.0 }, {}
        }
    };

    // loop version
    double sum = 0.0;
    for ( auto const& path : paths ) {
        for ( double d : path.distance ) {
            sum += d;
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    // ...
```

algorithm version

```
    std::cout <<
        std::accumulate(
        paths.begin(),
        paths.end(),
        0,
        [](double res, Path const& path) {
            return res + std::accumulate(
                          path.distance.begin(),
                          path.distance.end(),
                          0);
        })
     <<std::endl;
}
```

`->` [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mI6NpW)

- use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)
- use [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) range-based loops if you insist on loops
- don't forget software design